# USB not working in Lineage OS 15

Tags: adb

Nexus 7 2012 (grouper).
Was running stock ROM (4.4.4), could connect via USB (e.g., as MTP for file transfer) and use `adb`).

Installed Lineage OS 15 (8/O). (Couldn't install any GApps at all because the `system` partition is too small.)
`fastboot` works as it should when booted into the bootloader.
`abd` works when it's booted into recover.

However, `adb` does not work when the tablet is started up and running LineageOS.
Nor does it appear as a disc drive.
In fact it doesn't even appear in Device Manager.
Windows doesn't make its noise when the device is plugged in (it *does* make its noise when connecting it in the bootloader and in recovery).

Developer options enabled:

- *Android debugging* is on,
- *Root access* is *ADB only*,
- *Select USB Configuration* is *MTP*.

It *has* to be something to do with LineageOS.
Any ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure, [(re)install Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)? The GApps shouldn't be the issue though.

Comment: AndroidStudio says version 12 already installed.Removed and installed again and no change.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem when I install Lineage 14 try tablet on another fresh windows pc that this tablet never connected before if tablet worked in MTP. Then try this steps:

1. Go to Windows Device Manager
2. Check `View hidden devices` from view
3. Find installed drivers from tablet and uninstall them all.

This is demonstration gif:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just installed Lineage 14 (N/7) and it's working normally, so it must be a problem with LineageOS 15 (`lineage-15.1-20200522-UNOFFICIAL-grouper.zip` to be precise).

Comment: Why voted down?